isAuth session doesn't work at first (messages too)
I got a problem with sessions. I made a navbar and added a condition isAuth if it's true username and logout will appear if it's false login and register will appear then. But when I login successfully navbar doesn't change still login and register links stay there but when i reload the page navbar changes and username and logout links appear.
            // Nav
                <% if (isAuth) { %>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link"><%= userName %> (<%= roles %>)</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/account/logout" class="nav-link">Log Out</a>
                </li>
                <% } else { %>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/account/login" class="nav-link">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/account/register" class="nav-link">Register</a>
                    </li>
                <% } %>
                
            // Locals Middleware
            module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
            res.locals.isAuth = req.session.isAuth;
            res.locals.userName = req.session.userName;
            res.locals.roles = req.session.roles;
            next();
            };
            
            // Post Login
            req.session.roles = userRoles.map((role) => role["name"]);
            req.session.isAuth = true;
            req.session.userName = userName;
            res.redirect("/");

